# C++ exceptions in main

Tags: c++, exception

My class Person has different files as attributes.

```
class Person {
private:
    fstream history;
    fstream familyTree;
public:
    Person() { 
        history.open("history.dat"); 
        familyTree.open("tree.dat");
    }
}
```

I need my program to return different values if any of the files couldn't be opened.

If history didn't open, return 1, if familyTree didn't open, return 2.

1) Is using exceptions the only solution for this?

2) Where are the exceptions launched?

3) Is it wrong if I catch exceptions in main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throw exceptions in your constructor and catch them in main.  Or you could catch the exceptions in your constructor and fix it so that the class can be correctly initialised whatever happens.

To make your class more testable, the constructor should do as little work as possible.  I would have two methods:

```
bool readHistory (std::string fileName)
bool readFamillyTree (std::string fileName)
```

instead of trying to do that in the constructor.  They would return true if the file could be read and was sane.  You could have a overloaded constructor that called those methods.  As was pointed in the comments, the constructor should return a usable object.  I am assuming that those files are not necessary for the object to function.  This could be erroneous.

Comment: I disagree. The constructor should do everything necessary to create a usable object; requiring the user to call post-construction initialisers, and handle errors by checking return values, is inconvenient and error-prone.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks.  Edited the answer to make things a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for exceptions here.

```
bool Person::IsHistoryValid() const
{
    return history;
}

bool Person::IsFamilyTreeValid() const
{
    return familyTree;
}

int main()
{
    Person person;
    if (!person.IsHistoryValid())
        return 1;
    if (!person.IsFamilyTreeValid())
        return 2;
    // do some work
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on your requirements, catching exceptions in `main` may be right or wrong. Of course, if you have to return an error code in case of exception, then you have to catch them.

Comment: +1 I like the IsValid() method but dislike the new constructor.  There is no requirement for having a tree only if a history is there.

Comment: This approach means that, whenever you add private state to the class, you have to find every place that instantiates it and add a new test. If you really must avoid exceptions (which in my opinion is a very bad idea), then a single `IsValid()` function is easier to maintain (although that does mean you can't meet the bizarre requirement of returning different error codes depending on exactly what failed).

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is using exceptions the only solution for this?

No. You can also record the error state in the constructor and have a method that returns it. Or you can do a two phase construction, where the contructor only does the parts that can't fail and you call a second initialization function to complete it.

I think exceptions would be the preferred method. If you are doing things that might need some cleanup if the constructor fails, do them on local variables and copy the results to the member variables at the end.

> If main() is the
>   closest stack call (is that well written?) to where the exceptions are
>   launched,
>
> 2) Is it wrong if I catch exceptions in main?

Absolutely nothing wrong with catching exceptions in main. In fact it's best practice to catch exceptions at the outermost level that can do anything about the error; often that means showing the error and shutting down the program, and main is the perfect place.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is using exceptions the only solution for this?

Certainly not, there are a lot of designs out there that predate the exceptions functionality that use return codes, double initialization, and such techniques. That said, if the construction of a `Person` requires opening both files, and you cannot do so, then throwing an exception is the preferred way to report it. Think about what it means for your design to be a `Person`, and to create a default constructed one.

> 2) Is it wrong if I catch exceptions in main?

No, is not. Plain and simple.